# Stepper Motor Everything in Order, Not Moving

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, mains

So I'm very confused. I have everything hooked up according to their various diagrams and am attempting to run the following recommended test code:

```
 void setup() { 
     Serial.begin(9600);      
     pinMode(2, OUTPUT);     
     pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(3, LOW);
 }

 void loop() {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(1);
    Serial.println("I got here");  
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); 
    delay(1);          
 }
```

[image: wiring]
Nothing is moving, and to be honest I'm a little terrified working with this power supply. Does anyone have a way of troubleshooting this that won't get me electrocuted? Also for anyone interested, it claims that it reaches "I got here" every time.

Comment: How long is delay(1) ?

Comment: What tools do you have available? Can you verify that the power supply is supplying whatever voltage you expect? Slow down your delay (delay(500)) and you can verify the stepping sequence with just a voltmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schematic does not include the enable pin. You'll need to pull that low in order for the drive FETs to be enabled. Not sure if there is an internal pull down. You also need to pull the sleep pin high.

As far as your power supply goes, 5V is not enough potential to shock you so have no fear. Check the coil resistance of your stepper too, I'm wondering if 5V is enough to drive the current your steppers need. Take a few of those, and call me in the morning.

Comment: you're correct. I misread the power supply spec sheet and thought it could go higher than 5V. Thanks for all your help.